# Gitlab Pipeline Trigger Rule

Tags: triggers, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

I have a repository on a gitlab instance for which I want to set up the deployment pipeline trigger.

I need a trigger rule which always triggers a pipeline if there is a new commit on "release" with a tag in SemVer format.

The repository is setup with two branches "main" and "release" ("release" is protected and it can only be merged into it, directly pushing is disabled).

The workflow is following:

- Developing and committing some changes to "main"
- Create a merge request "main"-> "release" and execute the merge (over the gitlab UI)
- Create a new tag (eg. "0.0.4") on the release branch  (over the gitlab UI)
  => now the pipeline should be triggered

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet and don't know why my version does not work. I thought this should work, it checks if a commit tag is in the specified format and if the commit is to the "release" branch.

```yaml
...
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v?\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/ && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "release"' 
...
```

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html under CI_COMMIT_BRANCH it says `The commit branch name. Available in branch pipelines, including pipelines for the default branch. Not available in merge request pipelines or tag pipelines.` that's because tags are not related to branches. So when you make a tag and the pipeline runs it will have no branch info in it.

Comment: So you will never get a pipelines where the ci_commit_tag AND ci_commit_branch are both set. It will always be one or the other. Never both

Answer (score 0):

TLDR (ctrl+f -> CI_COMMIT_TAG): https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Let's focus solely on Git to gain a clearer understanding.

When you tag in Git, you pin a label (like "version 0.0.4") to a specific Git commit.

In Git, a commit has ancestors, but a "branch" is just the current head of some line of development. Say differently, a commit captures the state of the project at a specific moment and can be associated **with multiple branches concurrently**.

So, thinking that commit can be associated with multiple branches, it is challenging for GitLab (and any other CI systems) to detect what branch you tag. That's why, when you tag, GitLab thinks about it as a standalone event, which is called **tag pipeline** (as opposed to **branch pipeline**), where $CI_COMMIT_TAG is available, but $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is not. And vice-versa.